# Install issues with Strapi on Ubuntu 18.04 using npm

Tags: npm, strapi

#### The environment

I am trying to install Strapi on a Google Cloud instance with Ubuntu 18.04. I have Node and npm installed (v. 10.16.3 and 6.9.0 respectively). I am encountering an error message after the npm install command.

#### Quickstart doesn't work

I have tried using the `$ npx create-strapi-app my-project --quickstart` option in the Quick Start Guide, but that just hangs on `Installing dependencies:  flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.`

#### The errors

Here's what I entered into the command line to install Strapi:

`$ npm install strapi@beta -g`

Here are the resultant errors:

```
npm WARN deprecated boom@7.3.0: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/boom. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues. 
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues. 
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules.
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules.
npm ERR! code EACCES 
npm ERR! errno -13 
npm ERR! syscall access 
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules' 
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access'/usr/lib/node_modules'] 
npm ERR!   stack: 
npm ERR!   'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access\'/usr/lib/node_modules\'', 
npm ERR!   errno: -13, 
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', 
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access', 
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' } 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system. 
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the 
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended). 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR!     /home/justme/.npm/_logs/2019-09-19T01_52_40_382Z-debug.log
```

Some warnings and some npm ERR!s Looks like a permission issue, but always been advised **not to run as root/sudo**.

#### What I expected...

To be able to progress to `$ strapi new my-project`

Answer (score 3):

You are either running this as root, or you are using sudo

`npm ERR! code EACCES`

This isn't a Strapi issue, you should -never- ever use npm as a root user or using sudo.

https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92

Comment: The command is not being run by root or using sudo privileges. The user is myname (not root) and the command is `$ npm install strapi@beta -g`

Comment: The permission problem seemed to be the npm default directory. Following the guide on how to change the default directory on the first link in @derrek-mehaffy's answer solved the EACCES issue, but unfortunately I am still suffering a hang on `Installing dependencies:  flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.` The process never gets past this.